# UIImageJPEGRepresentation vs UIImagePNGRepresentation for images in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to read images from the photo library. I use the following code to calculate their size:

```
if let file = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] {
    let imageValue = (file as? UIImage)!

    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageValue, 1)
    let imageSize = (data?.count)! / 1024
    print("imsize in MB: ", Double(imageSize) / 1024.0)


    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageValue) {
        let bytes = imageData.count
        let KB = Double(bytes) / 1024.0
        let MB = Double(KB) / 1024.0
        print("we have image size as MB", MB)
    }
}
```

To my surprise both tell a different size for the images, which is also different from size of image. What is happening here and which is more accurate?

A bit confused. Help is much needed to understand this.

Comment: *"which is more accurate"* - they are both accurate for their given representation of the image.

Answer (score 3):

Jpeg and Png are different. Here I googled the diffrence between Jpeg and Png on google.

The main difference between JPG and PNG is the compression algorithms that they use. JPG uses a lossy compression algorithm that discards some of the image information in order to reduce the size of the file. ... With PNG, the quality of the image will not change, but the size of the file will usually be larger.